# In-App Purchase Refunds

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

I looked for other question about this but there are some things that aren't very clear to me.
So I am asking my own question:

Currently, my Application stores SharedPreference if a User bought an Item.
Everytime the User navigates to the Shop Page,the InAppBilling Service is started and the Inventory is checked for Items. All my Items are not consumable.

Now I want to be able to issue refunds if a User ask for it.

1) I order the refund in my Google Checkout Account

2) User Recieves IN_APP_NOTIFY of PurchaseStateChanged

**What happens if my App isn't running? I wont be getting this Message and can't handle it?**

These Purchase change how the App is working,and as a purchase is refunded, I want to deny Access to these features.

**Are refunded Items removed from the Inventory?**

Is it therefore a good Idea to check the Inventory everytime the App starts and remove the Attributes in the SharedPreferecens if an Item is no longer in the Inventory of a User?

**And if I can handle these refunds through checking the Inventory, do I need to handle the PurchaseStateChanged at all?**